# configure subdomain nginx with unicorn

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I am using nginx + unicorn in linode.

This is my **nginx.conf**

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mydomain.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name  mydomain.com;
   keepalive_timeout 5;

  root /home/hyperrjas/mydomain.com/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # this is required for HTTPS:
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

      location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
                                root /home/hyperrjas/mydomain.com/current/public;
                                gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
                                expires max;
                                add_header  Cache-Control public;
                               }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

I want to add 4 subdomains:

```
imagescdn1.mydomain.com 
imagescdn2.mydomain.com  
imagescdn3.mydomain.com  
imagescdn4.mydomain.com
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use regex for server_name directive, i.e. something like this:

```
server {
    server_name   mydomain.com  ~^imagescdn\d+\.mydomain\.com$;
}
```

Refer to original documentation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) and [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) for more information.

Comment: Yes, you could just add www.mydomain.com to the list: server_name   mydomain.com www.mydomain.com  ~^imagescdn\d+\.mydomain\.com$;